# Cannot install centOS with Dell 21'' Monitor on VGA Input (input error on monitor)

Tags: display, installation, centos

I am trying to install on a machine which is connected on a 21'' Dell Monitor using the VGA input (on monitor).

during installation and when the X Server is trying to start, the monitor screen goes black with the message "Cannot Display this video Mode - Change PC Display input to 1680x1050"

What am i doing wrong? Can anyone help?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

X is trying to start at a resolution other than 1680x1050. The error doesn't tell you whether centOS is sending a higher or lower resolution to the monitor.

Do you know what modes the monitor will work in? It may support nothing except that one resolution, in which case X will probably not display correctly until you adjust some config files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues at install time, when you boot off the first CentOS disk and get to the installer prompt, type `linux text` and press ENTER to install the OS in text mode. This should get you through the install and then you can do some Googling (or come back here!) to fix resolution problems post-install if needed.